# Call DownloadFileAsync multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, download, webclient

I'm making a WPF application. I use WebClient's DownloadFileAsync to download files. I Download each file at a time from a folder. First time I call DownloadProtocol it works fine, but when i want to download a new folder with new files i then Call DownloadProtocol again my application freezes. I want more download in process in the same time.

```
            foreach (var x in res)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("111");
                await DownloadProtocol("http://cdn.something.com/rental/" + torrentId + "/" + x, savePath + torrentId + "/" + x);

            }

  public async Task DownloadProtocol(string address, string location)
    {

        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
        }
        /*while (client.IsBusy)
        {
            DoEvents();
        }*/
    }

    public void DoEvents()
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
    public object ExitFrame(object f)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;

        return null;
    }

    private void DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `while (client.IsBusy){....}`

Comment: The reason i have that while is because i want to download one file at a time from the current folder. @Eser

Comment: Then why don't you simply use async/await in a loop? (`DownloadFileTaskAsync`)

Comment: Sorry im new with thread programming i c#. But is it possible to use await inside a foreach? @Eser

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to download one file at a time

And without blocking your UI right?, *async/await* is a good fit for this. You can write a method `DownloadFile`

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string url, string fileName)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
        };
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, filename);
    }
}
```

and use it like here

```
async void SomeClickHandler()
{
    var urls = new string[] {
        "http://google.com","http://stackoverflow.com"
    };

    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        await DownloadFile(url, filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your implementation but it freezes my WPF application @Eser

Comment: @LocDaiLe Most probably you are doing something wrong. Above code can not block UI. This is the whole point of *async/await*

Comment: I'll also say it shouldn't, but it does? Will you please take a look at my implementation. Just updated my edit.

Comment: Seems like it works, but when im downloading a file and then want to download another one while the first is still running my app freeze/crash?

Comment: You said in comments `i want to download one file at a time` So I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @LocDaiLe If what you say is: *If click the button twice*, then you can start the same process in another thread and it may happen that two threads wants to write to the same file at the same time...

Comment: When i start a download I download from a folder. The folder contain several files these files i want to download one at a time. At the same time the first download is in progress i want to start a new downloading where I download from a new folder which also contain several files. Sorry if i haven't been clear enough about my problem @Eser

Comment: Yes. If I click a button twice it should start the same process. But it can never download from the same URL path, i have made it that way. Let say I want to download two folder, but in the same time. Right now I need to wait for the first folder to complete before starting a new download @Eser

Comment: @LocDaiLe The code you showed is now correct, but I have no idea about the rest of your code so I don't know why it doesn't work. I can only say that it is not related with above code...